# Forward an old url rewrite scheme to a new one?

Tags: plugin-development, permalinks, url-rewriting

I have the following url rewrite for custom post type:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'event/([0-9]+)',
    'index.php?post_type=event&p=$matches[1]',
    'top' );
```

Due to a site structure change, I'll be moving this from `/event/id` to `/workshop/event/id` like below:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'workshop/event/([0-9]+)',
    'index.php?post_type=event&p=$matches[1]',
    'top' );
```

How do I return HTTP 301 on the original url scheme, from within a wordpress plugin?

Comment: The best way to do this would be in your `.htaccess`, are you sure you want to do this with a Plugin?

Comment: Well, I understand it's doable with http server, but I actually have other related changes, and some of them (involving database queries) might be easier to handle in plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to keep both your rewrite rules active (for now).

On `single-event.php` you check for the URL, even before calling `wp_header()`.

If the URL does not contain the base 'workshop', add a `wp_redirect()`:

```
wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) );
```

This way you should be all set. If you do not like the `wp_redirect()`, you can of course just modify the header information with PHP.

I know this is not in the Plugin itself. If you really depend on the Plugin, you can do the same method by hooking into an early action.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a better mechanism?

Comment: None that I know about, if you do not want to use the htaccess. But if you know one, I am keen to learn!